# Не работают селекторы jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-form

Есть страница index.php с создаваемой формой:

```
<?php
require_once("class.php");
echo "test";
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Test Alphabetics</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .section {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    button {
      padding: 5px 16px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    button#changeQuota { background-color: yellow; }
    button#transfer { }
    button#buyTicket { background-color: #98fb98; }
    button#refundTicket { background-color: pink; }    
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>    
<link href='./app.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
";
$task = new Form("process.php", "Отправить данные");
$task->addFieldName("#f1");
$task->addFieldName("#opt");
$task->addFieldName("#f2");
$task->addFieldName("#exec");
$task->addFieldName("#res");
$task->displayForm();
echo "
</body>
</html>
";
?>
```

Форму создает нормально, все на месте, селекторы тоже на месте.

Результирующий html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Test Alphabetics</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .section {
      margin: 20px;
    }
    button {
      padding: 5px 16px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
    button#changeQuota { background-color: yellow; }
    button#transfer { }
    button#buyTicket { background-color: #98fb98; }
    button#refundTicket { background-color: pink; }
  </style>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>    
    <link href='./app.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./app.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='section'><h2>Введите данные</h2></br>
<input type='text' id='#f1'/></br>
<select required id='#opt'><option value='1'>*</option>
<option value='2'>/</option>
<option value='3'>+</option>
<option value='4'>-</option></select></br>
<input type='text' id='#f2'></br>
<button id='#exec'>Отправить данные</button>
<span id='#res'></span></br>
  </body>
    </html>
```

К индексу подключается app.js с таким содержанием:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("test");
$("#f1").html("3");
$("#res").html("Whoa!");
//Warmig up UI
$("#exec").click(function() {
    var f1 = $("#f1").val();
    var f2 = $("#f2").val();
    var opr = $("#opr");
    Calc(f1,f2,opr);
    console.log("test click");
  });

function Calc()
{
  console.log(f1);
  console.log(f2);
  console.log(opr);

  $.post(
  "/process.php",
  {
      f1 : f1,
      f2 : f2,
      opr : opr
  },
  onAjaxSuccess

  );
  function onAjaxSuccess (data) {
      var r=data;
      console.log(data);
      result=r.result;
      console.log(result);
  }
}  
});
```

И при этом не работает ни один селектор. Не задаются значения, не срабатывает функция и т.д. Вообще.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет как можно решить возникшую проблему.

UPD - поменял, теперь .val() выводит код элемента, например
    
А должен выводить значение..

Comment: можете вместо index.php прикрепить результирующий html?

Answer (score 7):

У вас неверно прописаны id элементов, [id не должен содержать символ `#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

Селектор `$("#f1")` ищет элемент с `id="f1"`, а не `id="#f1"`.

Перделайте php чтобы он возвращал такой html

```
<div class='section'><h2>Введите данные</h2></br>
<input type='text' id='f1'/></br>
<select required id='opt'><option value='1'>*</option>
<option value='2'>/</option>
<option value='3'>+</option>
<option value='4'>-</option></select></br>
<input type='text' id='f2'></br>
<button id='exec'>Отправить данные</button>
<span id='res'></span></br>
```

тогда селекторы в js будут работать.

UPDATE: У вас опечатка в одном из селекторов:

Второе поле в php имеет `id="opt"` (селект поле). В js коде вы пытаетесь получить `$('#opr')` (php "opt"-> js "opr" ).

UPDATE 2:
Ошибка в методе Calc:

`function Calc()`.
    Calc не получает никаких аргументов.
    В js можно передавать аргрументы в функции которые не собираются их получать,
    поэтому вызов `Calc( f1, f2, opr )` внутри click не вызовет ошибок.
    Нужно заменить на `function Calc( f1, f2, opr)`

Печать f1, f2, и opr

```
  console.log(f1);
  console.log(f2);
  console.log(opr);
```

В текущем варианте печатает узлы т.к. переменные f1, f2 и opr не существуют ни в локальной области видимости ни в глобальной. Когда js не может найти переменную ни в одной области видимости, он ищет узел с `id` равным названию этой переменной.

Comment: исправил, теперь возникла другая проблема - .val() возвращает код элемента, например 
    <input type="text" id="f1" value="2">
А должен возвращать значение.. что может быть не так?

Comment: Вы иммеете в виду в методе `console.log( f1 ) в методу  "calc"?
добавил в update2

Comment: да, именно так, выводит код вместо значения

Comment: доп информация по [глобальным переменным полученным чере id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381425/is-there-a-spec-that-the-id-of-elements-should-be-made-global-variable)

Comment: Но это не глобальные переменные, я же передаю их через функцию, нет?

Comment: Вы их передаёте, но не получаете (в вашей версии Calc игнорит всё что ей передано).

Comment: Ой, точно, сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 0):

jQuery должен подключться после декларации всех DIV и прочих DOM элементов в конце страницы.
Либо в теге HEAD